# SSL certificate verification failed when trying to build GraalVM compiler with mx

Tags: build, graalvm

I'm trying to build the [GraalVM compiler](https://github.com/oracle/graal) using the [mx](https://github.com/graalvm/mx) build tool. I've Python 3.10.4 and Java 17.0.2 in my PATH. However, when I run mx I get the following message:

```
Downloading COMMONS_MATH3_3_2 from ['https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar', 'https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar']
Error downloading from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.14.6/jline-2.14.6.jar to /Users/cesarsv/.mx/cache/JLINE_c3aeac59c022bdc497c8c48ed86fa50450e4896a/jline.jar: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>
WARNING: ** If behind a firewall without direct internet access, use the http_proxy environment variable (e.g. "env http_proxy=proxy.company.com:80 mx ...") or download manually with a web browser.
Error downloading from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12.2/scala-reflect-2.12.2.jar to /Users/cesarsv/.mx/cache/SCALA_REFLECT_12_fa13c13351566738ff156ef8a56b869868f4b77e/scala-reflect-12.jar: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>

...
```

The error seems to be related to an SSL certificate validation when downloading the dependencies necessary for the GraalVM build with mx. There is no clear solution for this issue in the GitHub repo of the used tools.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mx uses python to fetch the artifacts that it needs for the build from external repositories. Python 3.7 and above don't have any SSL certificates activated by default. Therefore, the scripts used by mx can't validate any SSL connections.

So I activate SSL in Python manually by creating and running the file [install_certificates.command](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/560ea272b01acaa6c531cc7d94331b2ef0854be6/Mac/BuildScript/resources/install_certificates.command) and it solved my problem.